# Firebase security rules for multiple projects

Tags: firebase, firebase-security

I would like to only allow authenticated user from one project to be able to read data from another project, but nobody else can access the data.

How can I accomplish that ?

Thank you

Comment: You can accomplish that by using firebase security rules probably. If you want a better answer you should improve your question and show us what you have tried already, why/how it failed, what your database structure is. Take a look at [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for more info about improving your question

Comment: I tried in a project A to only allow users from a project B (node "users") to be able to read data from project A. But it did not work

Answer (score 1):

Auth does not transcend project boundaries. You will need to authenticate the user into the project whose data you want to access. If you don't want to / can't do so directly, you will need to verify the token of Project A and then [mint a custom token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens) for Project B in a trusted environment such as a Cloud Function.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am new to Firebase, do you know where I can find a fully detailed tutorial/video to show me how to verify and mint tokens in a Cloud Function ?